# Convert multiple IF EXIST statments to something more readable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple levels of the following:

```
IF EXISTS(...)
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(...)
  BEGIN
  END
END
```

How can i just assign a variable a value and do this:

```
@doesXExist = IF EXISTS(...)

IF @doesExist
  IF NOT EXISTS(...)
  BEGIN
  END
END
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a boolean datatype. You can do

```
DECLARE @doesXExist BIT = CASE WHEN EXISTS(...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

(The combined `DECLARE` and set syntax is 2008+)

But you can't then do `IF @doesExist` you would need to do `IF @doesExist = 1` or `IF @doesExist = 'True'`